# Galois theory and Lie theory

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, galois-theory

Galois theory talks about solving algebraic equations by radicals and the motivation for Lie to develop his theory is to study differential equations.

I want to understand what is happening in common between these two important theories of Mathematics. Is it possible to consider an algebraic equation and a differential equation through which we can explain the analogy step by step by solving them?

Feel free to edit the question if it can be put it in a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: [Differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory)

Comment: Probably you want to consult the books by Thomas Hawkins and by Armand Borel to get the history right.

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175761/differences-in-philosophy-between-lie-groups-and-differential-galois-theory